# Wordpress Shortcode Styling

Tags: php, css, wordpress

```
add_shortcode( 'my_cat_list', 'my_list_categories_shortcode' );

function my_list_categories_shortcode() {   
    wp_list_categories(array(
        'style'    => 'list, list-style-type: none'
    )); 
}
```

That's the basic shortcode I'm using to show my category list. By far the code work just fine as a list. But I would like to add a float "left" action to this shortcode. So that the list items spreads evenly through the page rather than going long as list.

I Don't know PHP! I would truly appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do to find the class for it, is find it in your website and right click it. Then select inspect element. From there, you should be able to find the css class, which will then allow you to add it to your stylesheet.

Comment: I’d add that, per the WP docs on `wp_list_categories`, the default value is for `style` is `list`, but if that argument is left empty or any other value, you get each category, separated by `<br>` instead. You may wish to change that back to `'style' => 'list'`, or omit that altogether.

Comment: And if you’re looking for _where_ to add that CSS, that would be the `styles.css` file in your theme.